# Alamofire + SwiftyJSON not receiving last item in JSON object

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm running into a strange problem when extracting data from the last item in a JSON object. Basically, I have 14 items being returned, but when I try to grab an element from the last item, it says I only have 10. Here's my code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xyz.herokuapp.com/api/v1/purchases/", parameters: ["login_user": "admin@xyz.com", "login_password": "test123"])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                let dispenseToken = json["purchases"]["purchases".length-1]["dispense_token"]
                print(json["purchases"]["purchases".length])
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
```

The Purchases JSON object returns this:

```
    purchases =     (
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 759316;
        dispensed = 1;
        id = 2;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 41277;
        dispensed = 1;
        id = 1;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 877725;
        dispensed = 1;
        id = 3;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 5379;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 4;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 246309;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 5;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 573469;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 6;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 770184;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 7;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 199976;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 8;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 531909;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 9;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 608240;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 10;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 843961;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 11;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 938967;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 12;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 212041;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 13;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        "credit_card_id" = "<null>";
        "dispense_token" = 204030;
        dispensed = "<null>";
        id = 14;
        "machine_id" = 1;
        "payment_type" = "<null>";
        reserved = "<null>";
        "user_id" = 1;
    }
);
```

But when I print json["purchases"]["purchases".length], this is the result I get:

```
{
  "reserved" : null,
  "machine_id" : 1,
  "id" : 10,
  "payment_type" : null,
  "dispense_token" : "608240",
  "user_id" : 1,
  "credit_card_id" : null,
  "dispensed" : null
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"purchases".length` is not what you want to use. `"purchases".length` means the `length` of the string not the last element of the array...("purchases" has 9 characters and that's why you get the 10th element in the list.)

You want to use `.arrayValue.last` instead. Try `json["purchases"].arrayValue.last`

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it! You're completely right, I should have known better with how Strings work.